How do you make latte art with magnifica start
I have Magnifica Start and I’ve given up on milk suitable for art, but a few circles of froth with a skewer run through make perfect hearts and a line of froth across the centre of the cup with a skewer run backwards and forwards from top to bottom makes a beautiful fern.
